# Pandas to_csv correct way to handle UnicodeEncodeError

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, ascii

I'm processing a file csv file with pandas, so, I open it:

```
df = pd.read_csv(my_file, low_memory=False)
```

I'm applying some sanitizing functions, changing some strings to numbers, and then when I want to save the dataframe into a file I do this:

```
df.to_csv(output_file, index=False)
```

In some cases this throws a `UnicodeEncodeError`, so I want to know how to avoid this. I know there's an `encoding` parameter in the `read_csv` and the `to_csv` methods but whenever I have used it, it throws the error again.

I need to build a strong enough code that doesn't fail in the cases where the file has non-ascii characters. I know there's a parameter in the `str.encode` method, which is `ignore` and I would like to use something like that, but I'm not sure how to do it.

EDIT:

I know I can use encodings as `latin1`, `iso-8859-1` or some others to make it work, but I would like the output file to be encoded in either `ascii` (preferably) or `utf-8`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue openning a russian database. Try calling read_csv with encoding='latin1', encoding='iso-8859-1' or encoding='cp1252' (these are some of the various encodings found on Windows).

```
df= pd.read_csv('xxx.csv',encoding ='latin1')
```

Comment: I would like to avoid that, because I would like the output file to be in ascii or utf-8 encodings. Isn't there a way to avoid using these encodings?

Comment: you can try usingfile = open('xxx.csv', encoding='utf-8', errors = 'backslashreplace')
pd.read_csv(file)